# Regular Expression to match one or more backslashes and + signs

Tags: regex, perl

I am writing a regular expression to match one or more  `\` and one or more `+` signs.
This is what I have so far and it doesn't look like its right

```
/\\+\++/

my $test = "\+";

if( $test =~ /\\+\++/)
{

    print "yes";

}
```

Ive tried this code and it doesn't work

Comment: Looks right to me, can you give some examples of where it fails?

Comment: @sverre it fails when I have the string "\+".

Comment: It seems to fail whenever I have only one backslash in my string, I am intending to match 1 or more backslashes followed by one or more "+" signs.

Comment: @steffan-harris are you sure it's not just perl treating the \ as an escape character?

Comment: thats why I escaped the backslash, did I escape it right?

Comment: @Steffan: He's talking about your input string, not the regex. If your inputs string is simply \+ you're escaping the + and your test string is just '+' which does not match your pattern. You need to escape your input string as well.

Comment: @Steffan: FWIW you only downvote when the answer is blatently wrong and unhelpful - not because it doesn't magically solve your specific problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're expression is fine as is, though you may want to add anchors if the whole string should be made up of only \ & + characters.

```
/^\\+\++$/g
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks fine to me:

```
perl -Dr -e '"\\+++" =~ /\\+\++/'
Compiling REx "\\+\++"
rarest char + at 1
rarest char \ at 0
Final program:
   1: PLUS (4)
   2:   EXACT <\\> (0)
   4: PLUS (7)
   5:   EXACT <+> (0)
   7: END (0)
anchored "\" at 0 floating "\+" at 0..2147483647 (checking floating) plus minlen 2
Omitting $` $& $' support.

EXECUTING...

Guessing start of match in sv for REx "\\+\++" against "\+++"
Found floating substr "\+" at offset 0...
Found anchored substr "\" at offset 0...
Guessed: match at offset 0
Matching REx "\\+\++" against "\+++"
   0 <> <\+++>               |  1:PLUS(4)
                                  EXACT <\\> can match 1 times out of 2147483647...
   1 <\> <+++>               |  4:  PLUS(7)
                                    EXACT <+> can match 3 times out of 2147483647...
   4 <\+++> <>               |  7:    END(0)
Match successful!
Freeing REx: "\\+\++"
```